# What is the use of S-function in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created a simulink model and I need to convert it to C/C++ code using S-function. Can anyone tell me how to create S-function and where and how to use this to generate code?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [Simulink Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/), which allows you to generate C or C++ from models. Converting an entire model into an S-Function, like you're asking for in the question, is silly, and beats the whole purpose of model based design.

Comment: Then, where the S-function has to be used?

Comment: A few situations - you'd use them when you want to incorporate legacy functionality into the model, or you have some logic that doesn't readily translate to building with existing blocks, or something that you code better yourself than using the existing blockset. I recommend you read the (extensive) Simulink documentation on them, I'm not going to explain everything about them in SO comments.

Comment: @Praetorian is correct. If you just want to generate C/C++ code from Simulink, forget S-functions. They are a sort of DLL wrapped code, which only work in Simulink. Some of the possible use case for S-functions (and in my mind the only valid ones) are to distribute some Simulink functionality to end-users so that they can use it in their models, without having access to the source code, or to develop an interface between Simulink and a third party software. Even on the IP protection side, you can now generate protected referenced models, which are better than S-functions in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

S-functions (system-functions) provide a powerful mechanism for extending the capabilities of the Simulink environment. An S-function is a computer language description of a Simulink block written in MATLAB, C, C++, or Fortran. C, C++, and Fortran S-functions are compiled as MEX files using the mex utility

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Simulink Blocks which I Suppose you are telling to create a simulink model, you can use s-function builder to write your code and go for Matlab Coder for converting it to Embedded C-Code if you want to build your code on any Microcontroller